# trying to delete all of a user data from a database but how could I search for a particular column value instead of just the primary key?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Im using `.Find()` which searched for the table with the database but I need to find the value not using the primary key but instead the UserId.

```
ElearnUser loggedInUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email.ToString());

            var meta = _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Find(loggedInUser.Id);
            if (meta != null)
            {
                _elearnContext.UserMetaData.Remove(meta);
           }
```

*** this gets the value I need but is it also multiple rows***
I'm not sure if that will work when I pass it to the `.Remove()` My problem is that I cant use the  `var progresses` because it is queryable so my question is there anything like the `.Find()` that searches for any column variable. Also, will I need to run a loop to delete each row?

```
           var  progresses = _elearnContext.Progress.Where(p => p.UserId == loggedInUser.Id);
            
        
            if (progresses != null)
            {
                
               _elearnContext.Progress.Remove((Progress)progresses);
            }
```

Comment: Just call ToList after your where clause